# Median replace the empty values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called Reservation some of its rows is empty and some rows have several values.
I want to extract the letter before the numbers

```
print(df['Reservation'][:24])

0                  NaN
1                  NaN
2                  NaN
3                  NaN
...
24     B57 B59 B63 B66
```

I tried this.

```
df['Room'] = df['Reservation'].astype(str).str[0]
```

However i get the empty values like Nan in the result.

```
print(df['Room'][:3])
0     n
1     n
2     n
3     n
```

The result should be something like

```
print(df['Room'][:1])

 1           B
```

---

Then i have the table below, some of the Days_of_Reservations are empty, so i have to fill in those embty raws with the median of the same Profission and the same Organizations.
Like the first two raws they are Doctors from the same organizations, so themedian value should be filled in into the nan value.

```
 Organization    Days_of_Reservations     Profission
    or3               4                   Doctor
    0r3               Nan                 Doctor
    or2               2                   Teacher
    or1               3                   Teacher
    or5               Nan                 Dentist
```

I treid this i get this error.

```
med = df.groupby('Days_of_Reservations')['profission']['organization'].transform('median')
df['Days_of_Reservations'].fillna(med)
```

I get this error.

```
Exception: Column(s) ['profission'] already selected
```

Comment: this should be posted as 2 separate questions.

Comment: I provided an answer for the first question. Please delete the second question from this post and make it a separate post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first dataframe, the Reservation column should be an object already so you should be able to get the first non-nan character like this after dropping nans:

```
df['Room'] = df['Reservation'].dropna().str.get(0)
```

For your second question. You are using groupby backwards. The grouping columns go in the groupby method and the aggregating columns outside like this.

```
med = df.groupby(['Organization', 'Profission'])['Days_of_Reservations'].median()
```

You can then fill in the missing values with the following

```
df.set_index(['Organization', 'Profission'])['Days_of_Reservations'].fillna(med)
```

Edit: From your comments please test with the following code

```
# create data for first question
df = pd.DataFrame({'Reservation': [np.nan, np.nan, 'B57 B59 B63 B66']})

# get first letter of non na
df['Room'] = df['Reservation'].dropna().str.get(0)
print(df)
```

Ouput

```
       Reservation Room
0              NaN  NaN
1              NaN  NaN
2  B57 B59 B63 B66    B
```

#### Second question

Test this code

```
s=''' Organization    Days_of_Reservations     Profission
    or3               4                   Doctor
    or3               Nan                 Doctor
    or2               2                   Teacher
    or1               3                   Teacher
    or1               Nan                 Dentist
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
df['Days_of_Reservations'] = df.Days_of_Reservations.astype(float)
med = df.groupby(['Organization', 'Profission'])['Days_of_Reservations'].median()
df.set_index(['Organization', 'Profission'])['Days_of_Reservations'].fillna(med).reset_index()
```

Output

```
  Organization Profission  Days_of_Reservations
0          or3     Doctor                     4
1          or3     Doctor                     4
2          or2    Teacher                     2
3          or1    Teacher                     3
4          or1    Dentist                   NaN
```

Comment: For your first answer i get this error: 
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I've included the code on how I have generated the data. Please check and come back with comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want just the first character for each non-`NaN` entry:

```
import numpy as np

df['Room'] = np.where(df[0].notnull(), df[0].astype(str).str[0], np.nan)
```

see: [`numpy.where` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)